# CreateReactApp takes too much time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npx

When I create a react app with the command `npx create-react-app {name}` it takes too long to create. Any suggestions as to how I can make it faster?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY3Os.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something related to your bandwidth . Try to installing CRA in your local machine and install using `npm install -g create-react-app`, then use `create-react-app {name}` instead of `npx create-react-app {name}`.

Please note: this is the deprecated way of using CRA. Relying on npx means always using the latest stable version while in this case you have to update `react-scripts` yourself to remain up-to-date.